# How to get more accurate rotations from decomposing a homography matrix

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, homography, rotational-matrices

I am trying to create a program that can calculate the rotation of a plane from two images in python using opencv. I am doing this by finding the homography matrix that represents the translation, and decomposing it using the intrinsic camera matrix using the decomposeHomographyMat function in openCv.

I tested the accuracy using blender by creating a plane with a QR code on it, and then rotating it by known values [as seen here where the plane has been rotated by 15,30,15 in XYZ Euler coordinates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iVv5j.png), although I want the final program to take pictures of a plane being translated in real life.

The intrinsic camera matrix was found in blender using [this technique](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/15102/what-is-blenders-camera-projection-matrix-model/38189#38189). And also found using camera calibration in blender by putting a checkboard in and taking renders from multiple angles and translations.

However, when I run the code, the ZYX Euler outputs I get are [ 27.9 
, -25.4, -26.31] instead of [15, -30, -15] which is not accurate. Some other examples of the output to the code to expected values are below to give an idea of the accuracy of the code:

Expected - [0 -30 0]

Calcaulted - [0.82 -34.51  -1.91]

Expected - [0 0 15]

Calculated - [  0   0 -15.02]

Expected - [15 0 15]

Calculated - [ 16.23  3.76 -13.76]

I was wondering if there's any way to increase the accuracy of the rotation matrices calculated or whether this is the best accuracy that I can get, and if this is the best accuracy that I can get what other alternatives I can do in order to calculate the rotation of a plane in 3 axis from images (adding extra cameras can also be done).

Any help would be much appreciated!

The code I am using is shown below:

```
#Import modules
import cv2
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import glob
import math
########################################################################
#Import pictures
img1 = cv2.imread("top.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
img2 = cv2.imread("150015.png", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

#Feature Extraction
MIN_MATCH_COUNT = 10
sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()

kp1, des1 = sift.detectAndCompute(img1,None)
kp2, des2 = sift.detectAndCompute(img2,None)

FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE = 0

index_params = dict(algorithm = FLANN_INDEX_KDTREE, trees = 5)
search_params = dict(checks = 50)

flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

matches = flann.knnMatch(des1,des2,k=2)

# store all the good matches as per Lowe's ratio test.
good = []
for m,n in matches:
    if m.distance < 0.80*n.distance:
        good.append(m)

if len(good)>MIN_MATCH_COUNT:
    src_pts = np.float32([ kp1[m.queryIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst_pts = np.float32([ kp2[m.trainIdx].pt for m in good ]).reshape(-1,1,2)

    #Finds homography matrix
    M, mask = cv2.findHomography(src_pts, dst_pts, cv2.RANSAC,1)
    matchesMask = mask.ravel().tolist()

    h,w = img1.shape
    pts = np.float32([ [0,0],[0,h-1],[w-1,h-1],[w-1,0] ]).reshape(-1,1,2)
    dst = cv2.perspectiveTransform(pts,M)

    img2 = cv2.polylines(img2,[np.int32(dst)],True,255,3, cv2.LINE_AA)

else:
    print "Not enough matches are found - %d/%d" % (len(good),MIN_MATCH_COUNT)
    matchesMask = None

draw_params = dict(matchColor = (0,255,0), # draw matches in green color
                   singlePointColor = None,
                   matchesMask = matchesMask, # draw only inliers
                   flags = 2)

img3 = cv2.drawMatches(img1,kp1,img2,kp2,good,None,**draw_params)

plt.imshow(img3, 'gray'),plt.show()


#Camera calibration matrix
K = ((3,3))
K = np.zeros(K)

#Camera calibration matrix from blender python script
#K = np.matrix('1181.2500 0 540; 0 2100 540; 0 0 1')

#Camera calibration matrix from importing checkboard into blender
K = np.matrix('1307.68697 0 600.618354; 0 1309.66779 605.481488; 0 0 1')

#Homography matrix is decomposed
num, Rs, Ts, Ns  = cv2.decomposeHomographyMat(M, K)

# Checks if a matrix is a valid rotation matrix.
def isRotationMatrix(R) :
    Rt = np.transpose(R)
    shouldBeIdentity = np.dot(Rt, R)
    I = np.identity(3, dtype = R.dtype)
    n = np.linalg.norm(I - shouldBeIdentity)
    return n < 1e-6


# Calculates rotation matrix to euler angles
# The result is the same as MATLAB except the order
# of the euler angles ( x and z are swapped ).
def rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R) :

    assert(isRotationMatrix(R))

    sy = math.sqrt(R[0,0] * R[0,0] +  R[1,0] * R[1,0])

    singular = sy < 1e-6

    if  not singular :
        x = math.atan2(R[2,1] , R[2,2])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2,0], sy)
        z = math.atan2(R[1,0], R[0,0])
    else :
        x = math.atan2(-R[1,2], R[1,1])
        y = math.atan2(-R[2,0], sy)
        z = 0

    return np.array([x, y, z])

#Conver the 4 rotation matrix solutions into XYZ Euler angles
i=0
for i in range(0,4):
    R = Rs[i]
    angles = rotationMatrixToEulerAngles(R)
    x = np.degrees(angles[0])
    y = np.degrees(angles[1])
    z = np.degrees(angles[2])
    anglesDeg = np.array([x,y,z])
    print(anglesDeg)
```

The images I have generated from blender are as follows:

[top.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuRR4.png) (Ox, 0y, 0z)

[003000.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfK3J.png) (0x, 30y, 0z)

[150015.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dxiq6.png) (15x, 0y, 15z)

[153000.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qI8L.png) (15x, 30y, 0z)

[153015.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8iKQu.png) (15x, 30y, 15z)

[And here is an image with keypoints matching for the 153015.png comparison](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qpkJ2.png)

Comment: Can you upload also the images (`top.png`, `150015.png`) to be able to test the code? Can you show the images with the keypoints matching? What is the reprojection error with the estimated homography matrix? You can also try to use directly the corners to compute the homography matrix and see if you have better results. Finally, have a look at this [tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/4.0.1/d9/dab/tutorial_homography.html).

Comment: Thank you for responding, I have uploaded those images as well as some other rotations I have made and images with keypoints matching. The reprojection error should be 1 pixel as this is the value used in the RANSAC algorithm and the image with keypoints matching shows that the homography matrix calculated is accurate. I will try alternate methods of computing the homography matrix in order to improve accuracy and update the post soon.

Comment: It's always a good idea to calculate reprojection error by yourself. Try reducing the threshold of RANSAC's termination condition. 1 pixel seems too big for computer-generated images with no lens distortion.

Answer (score 0):

Euler angles are not unique. Many sets of Euler angles can map to the same rotation. Try using distance between the rotation vector as the criteria.